# Как в C++ с помощью инструкции switch извлечь корень квадратного уравнения?

Tags: c++

Нужно написать программу, которая с использованием инструкции выбора **switch**, вычислит корень квадратного уравнения  ax2+bx+c = 0, где переменные a, b, c вещественные числа вводимые с клавиатуры. (ax2 это ax в квадрате)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    double a, b, c;
    cout << "Введите коэфициент a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите коэфициент b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Введите коэфициент c: ";
    cin >> c;
    double d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (d < 0)
    {
        cout << "корней нет";
    }
    else
        if (d == 0)
        {
            double x = -b / (2 * a);
            cout << "корень x = " << x;
        }
        else
        {
            double x1 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
            double x2 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
            cout << "корни уравнения x1 = " << x1 <<  ",x2 = " << x2;
        }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему местные так сильно желают увидеть что уже человек сделал? Не хотите отвечать не отвечайте, никто вас не принуждает. Зачем же минусить? Вдруг кто-то поможет человеку?

Comment: Я решил эту задачу  без switch

Comment: но мне нужно со switch

Comment: если не ясно для чего её использовать, то добавьте  в конце switch(1) { }

Comment: Нет, должно выть вот так:

Comment: switch (извлечение_корней)
    {
    case 0 : cout << "нет корней." << endl;
    break;
    case 1 :

Comment: Ну... тут три случая - соответсвенно три кейса в свиче.  `switch(сигнум(дискриминант)) { case -1: .... case 0: .... case 1:}`

Comment: ...и `сигнум(d)` можно записать как `(d>0)-(d<0)`.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Это даже в правилах есть: *"Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить."* (с) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Извините, я не просил сделать домашнее задание за меня, я задал конкретный вопрос!

Comment: @RomanBarnasiuk Это не обвинение в вашу сторону, сейчас с вопросом уже все нормально. :) Просто объясняю мсье pepsicoca1, почему мы просим добавлять код в вопрос.